# Inferencing on live stream using OpenCV.JS

Tags: javascript, opencv, computer-vision, html5-video, video-processing

I want to perform inferencing on video file (e.g. .mp4) using opencv.js. My current code uses browser function `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` to access local hardware via the web browser.

**Problem:**
I want to use a video stream from some other sources instead of the local hardware (webcam), for example I want to use a streaming URL of video source file.

After some searches I came to know that OpenCV.js has `cv.VideoCapture(video)` method that can be utilized for this task as it is often used in Python library. But I am not familiar with OpenCV.js.

Can someone please show how to integrate such OpenCV.JS code in my own code below for achieving this task?

**main.js**

```
$(function () {
    const video = $("video")[0];

    var model;
    var cameraMode = "environment"; // or "user"

    const startVideoStreamPromise = navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
            audio: false,
            video: {
                facingMode: cameraMode
            }
        })
        .then(function (stream) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.onloadeddata = function () {
                    video.play();
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        });

    var publishable_key = "rf_5w20VzQObTXjJhTjq6kad9ubrm33";
    var toLoad = {
        model: "egohands-public",
        version: 9
    };

    const loadModelPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        roboflow
            .auth({
                publishable_key: publishable_key
            })
            .load(toLoad)
            .then(function (m) {
                model = m;
                resolve();
            });
    });

    Promise.all([startVideoStreamPromise, loadModelPromise]).then(function () {
        $("body").removeClass("loading");
        resizeCanvas();
        detectFrame();
    });

    var canvas, ctx;
    const font = "16px sans-serif";

    function videoDimensions(video) {
        // Ratio of the video's intrisic dimensions
        var videoRatio = video.videoWidth / video.videoHeight;

        // The width and height of the video element
        var width = video.offsetWidth,
            height = video.offsetHeight;

        // The ratio of the element's width to its height
        var elementRatio = width / height;

        // If the video element is short and wide
        if (elementRatio > videoRatio) {
            width = height * videoRatio;
        } else {
            // It must be tall and thin, or exactly equal to the original ratio
            height = width / videoRatio;
        }

        return {
            width: width,
            height: height
        };
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizeCanvas();
    });

    const resizeCanvas = function () {
        $("canvas").remove();

        canvas = $("<canvas/>");

        ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

        var dimensions = videoDimensions(video);

        console.log(
            video.videoWidth,
            video.videoHeight,
            video.offsetWidth,
            video.offsetHeight,
            dimensions
        );

        canvas[0].width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas[0].height = video.videoHeight;

        canvas.css({
            width: dimensions.width,
            height: dimensions.height,
            left: ($(window).width() - dimensions.width) / 2,
            top: ($(window).height() - dimensions.height) / 2
        });

        $("body").append(canvas);
    };

    const renderPredictions = function (predictions) {
        var dimensions = videoDimensions(video);

        var scale = 1;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {
            const x = prediction.bbox.x;
            const y = prediction.bbox.y;

            const width = prediction.bbox.width;
            const height = prediction.bbox.height;

            // Draw the bounding box.
            ctx.strokeStyle = prediction.color;
            ctx.lineWidth = 4;
            ctx.strokeRect(
                (x - width / 2) / scale,
                (y - height / 2) / scale,
                width / scale,
                height / scale
            );

            // Draw the label background.
            ctx.fillStyle = prediction.color;
            const textWidth = ctx.measureText(prediction.class).width;
            const textHeight = parseInt(font, 10); // base 10
            ctx.fillRect(
                (x - width / 2) / scale,
                (y - height / 2) / scale,
                textWidth + 8,
                textHeight + 4
            );
        });

        predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {
            const x = prediction.bbox.x;
            const y = prediction.bbox.y;

            const width = prediction.bbox.width;
            const height = prediction.bbox.height;

            // Draw the text last to ensure it's on top.
            ctx.font = font;
            ctx.textBaseline = "top";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.fillText(
                prediction.class,
                (x - width / 2) / scale + 4,
                (y - height / 2) / scale + 1
            );
        });
    };

    var prevTime;
    var pastFrameTimes = [];
    const detectFrame = function () {
        if (!model) return requestAnimationFrame(detectFrame);

        model
            .detect(video)
            .then(function (predictions) {
                requestAnimationFrame(detectFrame);
                renderPredictions(predictions);

                if (prevTime) {
                    pastFrameTimes.push(Date.now() - prevTime);
                    if (pastFrameTimes.length > 30) pastFrameTimes.shift();

                    var total = 0;
                    _.each(pastFrameTimes, function (t) {
                        total += t / 1000;
                    });

                    var fps = pastFrameTimes.length / total;
                    $("#fps").text(Math.round(fps));
                }
                prevTime = Date.now();
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                console.log("CAUGHT", e);
                requestAnimationFrame(detectFrame);
            });
    };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Roboflow Demo</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable=no" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/3.2.0/async.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-6K6+H87tLdCWvY5ml9ZQXLRlPlDEt8uXmtELhuJRgFyEDv6JvndWHg3jadJuBVGPEhhA2AAt+ROMC2V7EvTIWw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.roboflow.com/0.2.22/roboflow.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="loading">
    <video id="video" autoplay muted playsinline></video>
    <div id="fps"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively straightforward: in your HTML code, you need to modify the `<video>` element (assuming that you only have a single one) to point to the file you want to process (example courtesy of https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp):

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Take care that the video is in a format that is directly playable by the browser, i.e. this means mostly H.264 or VP9. And then, you can remove the `startVideoStreamPromise` from `Promise.all` and just call `video.play()` directly in the `then()` part.

Comment: Your answer would be stronger if it showed **how to replace** the current (webcam) code of `video.srcObject = stream;` with the MP4 of your video tag. It's not obvious to future readers how simply adding `<video>` tag will make everything work and where to put your shown code? For example: could `const startVideoStreamPromise` be adjusted to make it work? (I suspect it doesn't need removing but instead it could be the actual opportunity for a solution)

Comment: I tried to make it a bit clearer, but assuming there is only one video tag in the HTML code (which isn't shown in the question), then there is nothing to change in my answer. If you don't remove startVideoStreamPromise from Promise.all, then the browser will still try to open the camera instead.

Comment: nothing is working as suggested. I am trying example from https://demo.roboflow.com/egohands-public/9?publishable_key=rf_5w20VzQObTXjJhTjq6kad9ubrm33. You can download code. I want to use video file .mp4 or live stream from ESP32 cam (e.g. http://192.168.236.247:81/stream) instead of webcam.

Comment: Okay, so the example you linked to has nothing to do with OpenCV, it's using some apparently non-free library called Roboflow. That being said, I already understood that you want to use a video from a file, that's why I suggested that you edit the video tag in the HTML file to point to the video file as above. And I checked, the HTML in question does indeed contain exactly one video tag.

Comment: Ok, so what to update in javascript code?

Comment: See second part of my answer: "remove the `startVideoStreamPromise` from `Promise.all` and just call `video.play()` directly in the then() part."

Answer (score 0):

> *"My current code uses `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` to access local hardware via the web browser."*

If your code is working fine (I did not test it) and you simply need to replace the video tag's input "source" then try my code example below.

As a starting point, it aims to keep the usage of the current code's  `Promise.all([startVideoStreamPromise, loadModelPromise])` to avoid breaking anything. Later on you can streamline (shorten) the code as according to the advice in [@FlorianEchtler's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75832962/2057709).

##### Possible solution:

Try replacing this starting part of your **main.js**:

```
const video = $("video")[0];

var model;
var cameraMode = "environment"; // or "user"

const startVideoStreamPromise = navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: {
            facingMode: cameraMode
        }
    })
    .then(function (stream) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.onloadeddata = function () {
                video.play();
                resolve();
            };
        });
    });
```

With this modified version (it accesses your video object and gives it your URL as file path):

```
var model;

//var cameraMode = "user";
var cameraMode = "environment";

//# set your video file path to load
var myURL_video = "https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mp4/sample_640x360.mp4"; 

//# access the video tag
const video = document.getElementById("video");
//const video = $("video")[0]; //# or if you prefer the JQuery version

var startVideoStreamPromise =  new Promise(function (resolve) 
{
    //# prepare what to do when video data is loaded
    video.onloadeddata = function () 
    {
        if (video.readyState >= 3) 
        {
            video.muted = true;
            video.play(); resolve(); 
        }
    };
    
    //# double-check that the URL is correct before using
    alert("myURL_video is : " + "\n" + myURL_video);
    
    //# now load the video file
    video.src = myURL_video;
    video.load();
});
```